# What do we exactly mean by P(Y=y|do(X=x), M=m)?

Tags: conditional-probability, causality, intervention-analysis

I know that P(Y=y|do(X=x)) is different from P(Y=y|X=x) in that the former is an interventional probability where the intervention is applied to the entire population, whereas the latter is a straightforward conditional probability where we simply condition on X taking on value x. But how would we read something like P(Y=y|do(X=x), M=m)? Would it be read as the probability of "Y taking on value y given that we intervene on X (with respect to Y) to set X=x and given that we restrict the population to where M takes on value M=m"?

If this were true, we could, conceptually speaking, first intervene on the entire population to set X=x and then restrict the population to M=m, or the other way around, i.e., first restrict the population to M=m and then intervene on this sub-set to set X=x. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An intervention on $X$ removes incoming edges to $X$

What you describe is broadly correct. One thing to be careful about is that performing the intervention $\text{do}(X=x)$ normally also implies removing all edges into $X$, such that its value is determined exclusively by the intervention.

### $\text{do}(X=x)$ comes before $M=m$

The general idea of sampling from a DAG is that first all exogenous values (noise parameters) are sampled, and then their values are propagated through the DAG. An intervention is like an exogenous value – the intervened-upon variable takes the intervention value (and nothing else), which is propagated through the DAG.
You would not know what $m$ the variable $M$ takes before the propagation, so there isn't a way to "restrict to $M=m$ before having already sampled by propagating the exogenous variables (including the intervention) through the DAG.

I would recommend to think about it as rejection sampling: You sample many times from the DAG with intervention $\text{do}(X=x)$ and keep all instances where $M=m$.